# Reading the motto of Obispado de Cuenca

Tags: ecclesiastical-latin, christianity, abbreviations, transliteration

[image]

There is a line of Latin handwriting on the logo of Obispado de Cuenca. What I can read is

> ego. julianus. dei gra coch(?) eps.

with unknown diacritics.

- **julianus** is seemingly [Julián de Cuenca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_of_Cuenca), a 12th century bishop of Cuenca;
- **dei gra** is certainly **dei gratiâ**;
- **eps** seems to be **episcopus**, a bishop;
- **coch**(?) is a bit obscure, which I can't find on the Latin abbreviation list. However I noticed that the Latin adjective form of Cuenca is **Conchensis**.

If I am right that the **coch** part is **Conchensis**, why **n** is dropped? I have read some manuscripts where a syllable final **n** is notated by a tilde on the vowel before. But here **gra**, **coch**, **eps** all have a diacritic. What's the purpose of it?

(By the way I am unfamiliar with Christianity.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tildes merely indicate letters have been omitted. This is most commonly used when the word or words in question are clear enough from context, have special meaning, or are formulaic. As you can see [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribal_abbreviation#Suspension), these marks are not rare at all.

The n in particular is a superscript type. It can be difficult to see, but it has the same general shape of the n in *Iulianus*.

While Medieval scribes largely had a shared convention, the particulars could differ from each other, so to definitely say how the marks above gra and eps are being used you would need to look at more of the manuscript / other manuscripts from the same school. In general, though, I wouldn't be surprised if they merely indicated that some letters are omitted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any purpose for the bar on the **h** of **coch**?

Comment: @KotobaTrilyNgian That's the more straightforward use of the bar: *-ensis* is omitted.